# AWS Lambda and TLS 1.2 Compliance

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, tls1.2

I am currently working on connecting to a rest service from an AWS Lambda function for an Alexa Skill. I am working in node.js and I am not quite sure how to test with a vendor that is looking for the server name as the domain and does not accept requests by IP to be TLS 1.2 compliant.

Normally I would be able to add an entry in a hostfile like

```
123.45.67.890 testserver #test server external address
```

and I would be on my way continuing to test. However, I don't have a host file. I have tried specifying the host in my request, but that doesn't seem to help.

What I am using looks something like this. I am able to test locally using a VPN from my local machine. Testing in AWS gets no response.

```
request.post({
    url: 'https://<server-ip>/thething/token',
    form: {
        grant_type:  "password",
        username: "username",
        password: "password"
    },
    host: 'TestServer01',
}, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
```

Comment: Do you mean that the vendor doesn't support TLS 1.2? You should probably find a different vendor. It's years since most services switched to TLS1.2, often TLS1.2 *only*. Your environment should allow falling back to TLS 1.1 though. The vendor should support *that* at least. Lower versions like TLS1.0 and SSLv3 are considered compromised. If they don't support even TLS1.1, stop using them as soon as possible.

Comment: DNS changes won't affect what TLS version is used to establish an SSL connection anyway

Comment: They do support TLS 1.2. In this particular instance for testing a rest service to be TLS 1.2 compliant the service does not accept requests to just the IP address.

Comment: Then don't use the IP address? Use a fully qualified name?

Comment: They reject requests to just the IP. Has to be to the domain name. For the testing instance the "domain name" is just the name of the server which would go no where without a DNS entry. If I were using an EC2 instance I would just use a host file.